# $('input[value=""]').size() not working

Tags: jquery, textbox

I have this html

```
<input type="text" value="" id="AA">
```

In Firefox 8.0.1, if I enter CCC inside the inputbox, inspect with Firebug still showing

```
<input type="text" value="" id="AA">
```

instead of

```
<input type="text" value="CCC" id="AA">
```

So when I

```
alert($('input[value=""]').size())
```

it produce 1 which should be 0. But when I

```
alert($('input[value=""]').val())
```

it produce CCC. So how to update the attribute "value" to reflect the actual value?

Comment: Are you trying to find the number of empty textboxes?

Comment: I don't think that firebug will automatically put the actual textbox value in its contents.. This will be a security problem I think.. especially when you are facing with password inputs

Comment: I agree. Don't think that it will update the DOM unless you do it manually.

Comment: To asprin, yes. I want to highlight empty textbox with css. BTW, I know how to do the long way using $.each() and count in every loop for empty .val().

Comment: There is no need to count. Check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing it would be:

```
var emp = $('input:text[value=""]'); // get all empty textboxes

// iterate over each of them and apply the css
$.each(emp, function(){
      $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cU7E4/1/

**UPDATE:**

As pointed out by Shaheer, it can be done with a single line of code.

```
 $('input:text[value=""]').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

Comment: Not working. Unless I loop it like
$('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="")
  $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
});

Comment: Nevermind. I checked the jsfiddle on FF, Chorme, and IE and it's working fine for me. No issues. You got what you were looking for.

Comment: I wrote ur code in a new blank html and test and its working. So that means something in my original project must has mess up but i can't find it. The selector '[value=""]' only applied to the initial value but using jquery .val() always return the correct value.

Comment: you could just do `$('input:text[value=""]').css('border', '1px solid red');` no need for a separate `$.each` :) http://jsfiddle.net/cU7E4/2/

Comment: I got it but can't understand it. Actually ur code is working. $('input:text[value=""]') is working but $('input[value=""]') is not.

Comment: That is because my code is specifying to search all inputs with type `text` via `input:text`      @Shaheer That's a better one.

Answer (score 2):

`value` is stored as a property not as an attribute, you can use `filter` method:

```
var len = $('input[type=text]').filter(function(){
      return $.trim(this.value) === ""
}).length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f5GwX/

Comment: I used the HTML from your fiddle. Hope you don't mind. Was feeling lazy to type in the html

Comment: Thank you this is working. But can't we achieve using smaller single line selector?